# How to pass locale parameter to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, devise

In my site, the locale is determined by a query parameter that is appended to the URL (e.g. http://www.mysite.com/mypage?locale=en).

I'm using devise with `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in my application controller, but couldn't figure how to pass the locale parameter to devise sign in view (If I manually add this to the view URL after it's presented, it does show the translated view, it's just passing the parameter that I can't figure out)

I added the following to my application controller, which didn't do the trick:

```
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently, Devise requires the method to be defined like that (and not like the rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) states):

```
def self.default_url_options
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

BTW, If anyone can explain the reason and the difference, please do.

Comment: No guys! That sucks! How is it possible? I need to put logic inside this method, access the request and host domain...how can I do?

Answer (score 4):

DeviseController doesn't inherit from ApplicationController so the only way to have access to default_url_options is to define it as class method on ApplicationController.

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:--Redirect-with-locale-after-authentication-failure) suggests `options.merge({ :locale => I18n.locale })`. Could you please tell me the difference?